# Execute REST Class via Site

Tags: apex, force.com-sites, apexrest

I have a class with a single method that creates some account records and related opportunities.
These records are clones from another environment that I JSON serialized and I want to execute the class by calling a REST endpoint to create the records in the target environment.

```
    @RestResource(urlMapping='/testdata')
    global with sharing class TestDataSetup{ 
        //@HttpGet what rest verb should I use here...?
        global static void init(){
            String parentAccount = '', childOpp = '';
            SObject[] records = new SObject[0];
            records.add(JSON.deserialize((Account)parentAccount, Account.Class));
            records.add(JSON.deserialize((Opportunity)childOpp, Opportunity.Class));
            Database.insert(records);
        }   
    }
```

I have created a site and added the class via the site settings.
I just need the class to execute in the target environment but unsure of what rest method to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to execute the class by calling a REST endpoint to create the records in the target environment
>
> //@HttpGet what rest verb should I use here...?

While you can use any annotation here, but because you want to receive a request and then create some records based on the request, you should use a [@HttpPost](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_http_post.htm) method here.

> The @HttpPost annotation is used at the method level and enables you to expose an Apex method as a REST resource. This method is called when an HTTP POST request is sent, and creates a new resource.

So your method should look something like this:

```
@HttpPost
global static void init() {
    ... all my code here ...
}
```